# Input and Output Impedance of a TTL NAND Gate

Tags: bjt, logic-gates, ttl, input-impedance

Basically I wanna know how to calculate the **input and output impedance of this basic TTL NAND gate**[image] I have looked at several books and websites but found nothing useful , can anyone help me please.
**thanks in advance**.

Comment: *impedance* is a term usually used for linear circuits (logic gates are not linear). If you insist, small-signal "impedance" changes quite a bit between logic high and logic low.

Comment: the terms input impedance and output impedance are usually used in any ic datasheet

Comment: anyway I just want to know how to calculate them for this circuit I really don't care what they are called

Comment: TTL logic was invented 56 yeas ago. New products have not been designed with it for at least 40 years. It had a high input low current and drew a fairly hiogh operating current all the time. Use a CD4xxx Cmos logic IC or a 74HCxxxx high speed Cmos IC that have an extremely high input impedance and very low operating current.

Comment: In the high output state, the output impedance is just R2. In the low state, the limit is the current that VT2 allows, which is a factor of the gain and R1, minus the current flowing through R2

Comment: The input impedance will sort of be R1, but the impedance of A is affected by the state of B, and vice versa

Comment: In the normal output low state, VT2 is saturated, so the output voltage is relatively constant for a wide range of sunk current values.  This makes the effective low-state output impedance quasi-proportional to the load impedance.

Comment: _" I wanna know how to calculate the input and output impedance of this basic TTL NAND gate"_ - why?

Comment: Zin,out for all BJT configs is widely known and nonlinear

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm reading this book about logic families where the author explains the operation of this gate and in the end he says that the output impedance equals (a certain number that I can't remember right now) so I just wanted to know how did he calculated that

Comment: thank u all for ur replies, but the thing is still a mystery to me, i don't fully understand this so can anyone point me in a direction where i can read more about this so that i can understand WHY dose it equal to what u guys said. and sorry for my English I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @Audioguru I'm just studying the subject I'm not designing anything.

Comment: @BeB00 first of all thank u for ur reply, from what i understand output impedance is like If this circuit is used as a source to another circuit, then that other circuit sees this much source impedance. so by that principal Zoh would equal R2 as u said and Zol would equal Rsat of VT2. is this actually true or am I making wild assumptions?, also can u elaborate more on Zin?, why dose it equal to R1? and again thanks

Comment: i wanna say again thank you all for your replies i actually  thought no one would reply, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Fundamentals: (link)](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/CB-vs-CE-vs-CC-transistor-configurations.html)

You may use KVL if you understand the Impedance of a nonlinear switch is based on the incremental resistance or impedance Z= ΔV/ΔI [Ω]  for either input or output then add in series each part of the loop.

You can test and measure this impedance using the Vbe-voltage-controlled (hi-Z) current-sinks of a common emitter, which we often use as an "active load". Or you can use the switched signal and measure the Zout from the change in voltage with a load applied and removed. ( A simple example is the Z is matched when the voltage changes 50% when Zo=R load.)

It also helps to remember Ic is controlled by Vbe and teachers always over-simplify to assume Vbe=0.7V but that is only true when Ic is large (20~100mA) and that Vbe number depends on the device but for small currents bulk resistance can be ignored so remember  this.

- for Ic = 1.00 mA or 997 uA for all devices, Vbe = 600 mV (0.6),

  - the changes below and above this are exponential.

[Here, I simulate & use](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%209.001713130052181%2050%205%2050%0At%20288%2048%20320%2048%200%201%200.48130868566966883%200.5680072674312459%2050%0Aw%20288%2048%20272%2048%200%0Aw%20240%2048%20208%2048%200%0At%20256%2016%20256%2048%200%201%200.5448148980047648%200.560937545893502%2050%0Ar%20320%20-48%20320%200%200%2010000%0Aw%20256%20-48%20320%20-48%200%0AR%20320%20-48%20320%20-80%200%200%2040%203.3%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20256%20-48%20256%2016%200%2015000%0Ax%20353%2054%20397%2057%204%2016%20output%0Ag%20192%2080%20192%2096%200%0Ag%20320%2064%20320%2096%200%0Ax%20249%2063%20267%2066%204%2016%20Q1%0Ax%20327%2053%20345%2056%204%2016%20Q2%0At%20160%2064%20192%2064%200%201%20-0.00972462167646293%200.5421599978660457%2020%0AR%20160%2064%20128%2080%200%203%2040%200.05%200.55%200%200.5%0A403%2096%20144%20224%20176%200%2013_64_6_4354_0.625_0.1_0_1%0Aw%20208%2048%20192%2048%203%0Ax%20187%2067%20222%2070%204%2016%20Qtest%0Aw%20320%200%20320%2032%203%0A403%2096%20192%20224%20224%200%202_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.00018063908772756273_0_2_2_3%0A403%20240%20144%20368%20176%200%201_64_0_12546_0.5798161595761635_0.0001_0_2_1_3%0A403%20240%20192%20368%20224%200%201_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.00012015557338181999_0_2_1_3%0Ar%20320%2032%20512%2032%200%20100000%0A403%20416%20144%20544%20176%200%200_64_6_12546_2.999999994801899_0.0001_0_1%0A403%20416%20240%20544%20272%200%200_64_1_4355_5_0.0001953125_0_1%0Ag%20512%2032%20512%2064%200%0A403%20416%20192%20544%20224%200%2018_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.0003258485477067021_0_2_18_3%0Ab%20224%20-96%20392%20107%200%0Ax%2041%2058%20148%2061%204%2012%20550%5CsmV%5CsDC%5Cs%5Cp/-%5Cs50%5CsmV%5Cs%0Ax%20411%2052%20444%2055%204%2016%20Rtest%0A) both active and passive load methods to demonstrate Ohm's Law and you may compute the incremental or min/max Z= ΔV/ΔI for each node. The wire or part will highlight in turquoise when the graph is selected and visa versa.

[image]

The current and Zin,out is dominated by the base resistance then the collector and then Rc resistance.

Each graph shows the signal Max,min.

I'll let you explore rather than explain everything until you ask a great question.

```
  But to help you get started here's a simplified logic table.

  Vin     Zin       Vout   Zout  (  for Rb=15k, Rc=10k  )

  "0"  Ve1/Ib1~Rb1   "1"    Rc
  "1"   >> Rb1       "0"  ~100 Ω
```